# fread unexpected output from empty file

Tags: c, file

```
FILE *hFile;
fopen_s(&hFile, "D:\\temp\\test.txt", "rb+");
char Buf[100]; 
int dwRead1 = fread(&Buf[0], sizeof(char), 10, hFile);  
fwrite("Hello,", sizeof(char), 6, hFile); 
int dwRead2 = fread(&Buf[0], sizeof(char), 10, hFile);
```

As I guessed, dwRead1 was 0. But why dwRead2 = 10, not 0 ?? In Buf I saw a garbage though I wrote only 6 bytes, and after them there was nothing else.

Comment: did you check `feof()` and `ferror()`?

Comment: @Mauren after first call fread() feof returns some positive number. after writing 6 bytes, feof returns 0. after reading 10 bytes of garbage - also 0

Comment: Weird. Have you opened this file in some editor such as Notepad++ to verify the existence of blank space or control characters?

Comment: @Mauren Yes in WinHex. It is totally empty (0 bytes)

Comment: Ah! I see you treat data as a string, but did you put a null terminator?

Comment: @Mauren no I didn't %) It doesn't matter( putting 7 bytes has changed nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing undefined behavior.

To quote from the `fopen` man page:

> When a file is opened with update mode ( '+' as the second or third character in the mode argument), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, the application shall ensure that output is not directly followed by input without an intervening call to fflush() or to a file positioning function ( fseek(), fsetpos(), or rewind()), and input is not directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

Putting `fflush` between the `fwrite` and `fread` calls should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call fseek(hFile, 0, SEEK_SET) to read "Hello," from the beginning of the file (if it was empty of course).
It all happen because fwrite(..) and fread() change position indicator of stream hFile and fread is trying to read right from the end of the stream in this case.

Comment: I did fseek after first fread. It didn't help, because first fread returned 0 and in this case position didn't change.